# Backwards and forwards automata languages compared with regular languages

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

[image]

Is every language accepted by a BAFDA regular? I am not even sure what the answer is. I tried thinking around canonical examples of non-regular languages (like $0^n1^n$ or $\{ww | w \in \{0,1\}^{*}\}$ provable by Myhill-Nerode or by the Pumping Lemma) but cannot think of a suitable BAFDA for any of them.

Update: I tried $0^{n+1}1^n$ with the two-state BAFDA "if the heads read different symbols, they stay at the same state; if they read different symbols, they switch states"- however, this accepts many more words than $0^{n+1}1^n$...

Hmm something like palindromes perhaps works! Take 2 states $(q_1, q_2)$, put the heads initially on $(q_1,q_2)$ and make only the pair $(q_1, q_2)$ accepting. While they read the same letter keep their state -- but if they read different letters then they switch states. If I am not mistaken, this BAFDA accepts all words $w_1\ldots w_k$ such that $w_i \neq w_{k-i}$ holds for an even number of indices $i$. On the other hand, this is an irregular language -- e.g. by the Pumping Lemma on sth like $0^{2p+1}1^{2p+1}$. Is this correct?

Update: Even palindromes should work with a similar example (just switch at the first time they read different letters; afterwards no matter what happens, do not change the states).

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).

Comment: Please give proper attribution to the source of all copied text, including the name of the book/article, authors, and a link to it (if freely available).  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing for guidelines.

Comment: I suggest you spend some more time on the problem, and then show us what approaches you have taken.  Have you tried to prove that every BAFDA-language is regular?  Have you tried working through some examples of BAFDA-languages, to see how you would convert the BAFDA to a DFA?

Comment: You can take inspiration from [two-way finite automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_finite_automaton).

Comment: It seems your model accepts the language of palindrome and the language $\{0^n 1^n : n \geq 0\}$. It seems plausible that it accepts a subset of the context-free languages.